# Material UI Autocmplete's disableCloseOnSelect is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using "@mui/material": "5.15.6", my requirment is to have autcomplete with checkboxes. User should be able to select multiple options from dropdown. for that reason I added disableCloseOnSelect, but it is not working.
it is getting closed automatically after I select checkbox.

***Note - I have n number of nested levels of Autocomplete.

Expected Result - Autocomplete should allow me to select multiple values from options.

Below is my code.

```
 const nestedOptions = (module?.children || [])?.map(
    permission => (
      <ProfilePermissionAccordion
        key={permission?.id}
        id={permission?.id}
        module={permission}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
    ),
  );

<Stack direction="column">
   <Autocomplete
              key={id}
              multiple
              fullWidth
              disableCloseOnSelect
              id={module?.id}
              options={module?.options}
              getOptionLabel={(option: any) =>
                option != null ? option?.title : ''
              }
              value={Object.values(
                module?.defaultSelection?.reduce(
                  (acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, { [cur.title]: cur }),
                  {},
                ),
              )}
              popupIcon={getIcon('ic_ionic_ios_arrow_down', null, 15, 15)}
              onChange={(event, value, reason) => {
                handlePermissionChanges(
                  event,
                  value,
                  reason,
                  module?.id,
                );
              }}
              ChipProps={{
                color: 'primary',
                // @ts-ignore
                deleteIcon: <HighlightOffIcon />,
              }}
              renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                <li {...props}>
                  <Checkbox
                    icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlank />}
                    checkedIcon={<CheckboxCheckedIcon />}
                    checked={selected}
                  />
                  {/*@ts-ignore*/}
                  {option.title}
                </li>
              )}
              renderInput={params => (
                // @ts-ignore
                <TextField {...params} variant="standard" />
              )}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                // @ts-ignore
                option.value === value.value
              }
            />
            {nestedOptions}
        </Stack>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
disableCloseOnSelect={!!multiple}
```

Make you condition like this when you have multiple seleciton so make it false otheriwse true